# How to load RSA public key from String for signature verification in Java?

Tags: java, rsa, public-key, pem

I have the following public key, that is stored in the DB (PostgresSQL) as text. It's a String, in java:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----     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==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I don't know how this key has been generated, I'm sorry. I have been told to take this key and verify the signature of another string that I'll call "object". I have been told that the algorithm that I have to use to verify "object" is SHA256withRSA.

So, I have written the following java method to read the key

```
private PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    publicKey = publicKey.replaceAll("\\n", "");
    publicKey = publicKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    publicKey = publicKey.replace("-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    publicKey = publicKey.trim();
    byte[] keyDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey.getBytes());
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyDecoded);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(publicSpec);
    return pubKey;
}
```

The point is that I get the following exception:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not
>   a sequence

I have read plenty of qustions as mine in stackoverflow. The code written by other users is pretty similar (sometimes identical) to mine. So I definitely don't get why it doesn't work for me. Other developers (workmates) are doing the same in php and it works great, so I would discard the hypothesis of wrong public key. Maybe didn't I understood the process clearly? Do you have any clue, please?

I have also tried to cope with the problem using BouncyCastle library, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence), but I get the same exception. The following is the code I have written:

```
private static PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    PemReader pp = new PemReader(new StringReader(publicKey));
    PemObject pem = pp.readPemObject();
    byte[] content = pem.getContent();
    pp.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(content);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algid parse error, not a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence)

Comment: Why is he trying to verify the signature with private key instead of public key?

Comment: I'm reading the question you cited. I'll fix and integrate. Give me some minutes, please.

Comment: The public key seems to be an RSA4096 bit key (One ASN.1 sequence containing the modulus and the exponent). Do you use a recent version of Java? Otherwise you may be limited by the old crypto restriction policy which forbids RSA keys larger than 2048 bit.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8

Comment: @DorianGray, I have edited my qustion. Could you please read my edits before closing it? Thank you

Comment: @Robert, I'm using java 1.8. A solution could be to find out a way to get modulus and exponent from the rsa text?

Comment: I asked for the exact version, not the main version. Just make sure you are using Java `1.8.0_201`.

Comment: @Robert, I'm using 1.8.0_171

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883499/150978) 1.8.0_171 should be new enough to work with RSA 4096 bit keys.

Comment: Peter: it's not enough to use PemReader; you must use **PEMParser** as Robert's answer AND #6559272 did. @Robert: Sun/Oracle Java crypto policy (below 8u151) never limited RSA, only symmetric; java 5 supported RSA-4096 just fine. I _think_ IBM may have been different as they had, and still have, their own cryptoproviders, but in any case that would have given a totally different exception. (And OpenJDK once released mid-6 didn't have the policy at all.)

Comment: @dave_thomson_085: You are wrong RSA was limited, however it seems like this limitation was removed much earlier. At least in Java 1.4 it was limited: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load that key using an X509EncodedKeySpec. According to it's [JavaDoc documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) it expects the following format:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
   algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
   subjectPublicKey BIT STRING }
```

Instead your key looks different. I used the data from your post, converted it to hex data and posted it into the online [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIICCgKCAgEA1ht0OqZpP7d_05373OE7pB7yCVGNGzkUEuCneyfOzps6iA03NbvI1ZL0Jpp_N3AW73lGdhaoa3X3JE4GsI_bsToVLQwTKmIOC4yjTvBctmFEoyhhTfxWs1UHZKl4XZ_7THbRlKHhRaTKyfDAbikkMAxNT_qutLAPjnN1qOwjb1oRq52NP6FJKWTTikz4UeOHroX-Xthn2fJSJDlQ4YMdBbgrZVx5JcHKNuPTKRf5gI8QQKMSA9Q9QJRE5OGp7b6dG14ZmOUnUxb00Mp20LgcaGPcuWU-oFsbQaF6W4G4bdkSZRJJXhSgd4Q7mahpar94_gnztJmth0GzqTWUYyZIWNqIFoMwuOgeaiDV43zb3uLsRVpRKYYyesmzcOy_jTScVLRCD8QRyu9B2wgCkNAVztQOXPCOOa4O1LlVQWaecIs4WPhOqDhiKTBhyVkpC1TrrBkp-QMqMqWll1OyVb6k_7uV0qE_i6rHJtjo5v9bcIgYzswyx9CD9PKl2Q0L0Jg7TMG-yLDIrLfGeuSeEc4XYJzN7bJcCeiizzu5iU9dQUkrncOrq9jnUb2pM_-A-JqIsoPK3IY_pJKqH4JYpGKhO1iPQF6iXIZT1r3ZgJUSQtzSeyYqhkla2uR2BsbPbDqebCuXm3lAsY5w-dujijcn96PKwYha1LsK5sACHuJ79AMCAwEAAQ).

The output is this:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  INTEGER (4096 bit) 873481340827968071893572683200799871431146795599597693981565010037737…
  INTEGER 65537
```

As you may recognize your key does not contain an `AlgorithmIdentifier` therefore it can not be loaded using `X509EncodedKeySpec`.

My suggestion would be to use the BouncyCastle library and it's `PEMParser` class for loading this key:

```
File pemFile = new File("test.pem");
try (PEMParser pp = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pemFile)))) {
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjPubKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) pp.readObject();
    RSAKeyParameters rsa = (RSAKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(subjPubKeyInfo);

    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsa.getModulus(), rsa.getExponent());
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    java.security.PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(rsaSpec);
    System.out.println(publicKey);
}
```

Or you manually convert the key to PKCS#8 format via openssl.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Robert. Why now I get "Signature length not correct: got 9575 but was expecting 5122", if I try to sign with that key?

Comment: Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initVerify(getPublicKey(publicKey));
signature.verify(object.getBytes());

Comment: @Peter You forgot to pass the data to be verified to your `Signature` instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46225417/150978

Comment: @Peter I solved your original question, the key is now loaded. Please stop modifying the question - I dislike "moving targets". Search Stackoverflow for similar problems and if you don't find a matching problem open a new question for a new problem instead.

Comment: This Q is for a public key; PKCS8 is for private key. OpenSSL 1.0.0 up (but not documented until 1.1.0) can convert this format to SPKI (what Java calls X509Encoded and OpenSSL calls PUBKEY) with `openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in <in >out`